# ALTER COMPILE of Package Body Does Not Populate DBA_ERRORS table

Tags: database, oracle11g

I have a database package `MAINLOAD` which is imported from schema A to schema B.

In schema A, this object is valid. In schema B, this object becomes invalid because of DB Link error.

This object appears in `DBA_OBJECTS` table after import, but its error message does not appear in `DBA_ERRORS` table.

Now, when I try to compile this object by issuing command: `ALTER PACKAGE MAINLOAD COMPILE BODY`, then this package fails for compiling because of DBLink error, but it still does not appear under `DBA_ERRORS` table.

But, when I manually compile this object by `SQLDEVELOPER` tool/ any other development tool, this object starts appearing under `DBA_ERRORS` table.

I tried by issuing command - `DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA` also, but no luck.

I have a utility which compiles all Invalid Objects present under `DBA_OBJECTS` table and then prints the error message on the screen using `DBA_ERRORS` table.

I am unable to understand why this kind of difference is there in both the processes.

Also, would like to know if there is any option by which this `DBA_ERRORS` table will get populated without manual compilation.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,
Ashis Sahay

Answer (score 0):

I assume you execute `ALTER PACKAGE MAINLOAD COMPILE BODY` from SqlDeveloper.

After you execute this command SqlDeveloper most probably issued either commit or rollback on the connection, so you data disappears.  Try to do the same from sqlplus and you will see.

Comment: I also recall, it does not work well, when you execute `alter session set current_schema=...`.  The sqlplus command `show errors` does not show anything, when you switch sessions schema. Or maybe try to select from `SELECT Line,Text FROM sys.All_Errors`

Comment: The error is not appearing in DBA_ERRORS/USER_ERRORS/ALL_ERRORS. I get this error -   SQL> alter package MAINLOAD compile body;
alter package MAINLOAD compile body
                                                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04052: error occurred when looking up remote object
MAINLOAD@MCC
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-02020: too many database links in use